# Change subnet address range of a subnet in Vnet

Tags: networking

I want to know if i can change the Subnet Address Range of a Subnet in a Vnet.
I created a Vnet with the adddess space of 12.0.0.0/24, while creating a subnet i gave the same address range (this was a bad mistake). Now i am trying to connect this Vnet to anther Vnet, but this Vnet (12.0.0.0/24) is not able to create a Gateway subnet since I have already assigned the full address space in the subnet I created (a bad mistake). Any suggestions on how to change the adddress block of the subnet I created.Can I delete this subnet using azure power shell or any other means.

Answer (score 0):

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/d23d0356-9dc5-4164-982e-8b2cc478e368/cannot-delete-or-modify-subnet-while-in-use?forum=WAVirtualMachinesVirtualNetwork has further information. If you aren't using the subnet, you should be fine to delete them.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/resourcemanager/AzureRM.Network/v1.0.13/AzureRM.Network?redirectedfrom=msdn has the list of Azure Networking cmdlets.

Remove-AzureRmVirtualNetwork would probably be the one you need.

You are also using 12.0.0.0, this is a Public IP range. You should be using a private IP range. Further information here: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc958825.aspx

Thanks, Tim.